# NullPointerException on Log.i during new startActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with one variable.
I get some data from my database after login, to fill my listView.

All works well, but at the end of my AsyncTask, I call a method which name 
**set_tour_id** which save an id on private variable of my class (which called the asynctask).

Like this, I can put this variable in an intent, because I want to get this, on the other activity.

But I have a **nullPointerException** on my Log.i after the activity.putExtra whereas I know that my private variable tour_id is not null, because I put an other Log.i of this variable, and I have my data that I want to send.

So this is the end of my AsyncTask in OnPostExecute, the variable **this.lcp** is the variable of my class which contain the method:

```
try {
    if(json_data.has("tour_id")){

        tour_id = json_data.getString("tour_id");
        this.lcp.set_tour_id(tour_id);
        Log.i("OnPostExecute -> after setAdapter -> tour_id ", tour_id);

    }else{
         Log.i("json_data of tour_id", "don't exist");
         }

    } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

there are no difficulty here..
This is my method **set_tour_id**:

```
public void set_tour_id(String new_tour_id){
    this.tour_id = new_tour_id; 
    Log.i("ListCrossingPoint_tour_id", this.tour_id);       
}
```

Here, I have my tour_id in the LogCat, so Normally all work well.

And this is the method **onOptionItemSelect(MenuItem Item)**:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {     
    case R.id.menu_tour_inf:
        Intent activiteT = new Intent(ListCrossingPoint.this, InfoTour.class);
        activiteT.putExtra("tour_id", this.tour_id);
        Log.i("tour id OnClickItemSelected", this.tour_id); 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       my error appear just here (on the top :-) )

        startActivity(activiteT);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So my error is here, whereas there is something in my variable **tour_id**
.. I don't understand why ....

This is the LogCat:

```
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.listpoint.ListCrossingPoint.onOptionsItemSelected(ListCrossingPoint.java:263)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:958)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:514)
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:99)
....
```

EDIT 1: This is my LOGCAT when my asynctask is finnish:

```
03-14 09:17:13.691: I/AsyncTaskListCrossingPoint(1351): onPostExecute
03-14 09:17:13.699: I/JARRAY(1351): [{"zip_code":"21500","tel":"03 80 91 54     54","end_hour":"18:00:00","type":"Collection","city":"Montbard","id":"1","closed_client":nul    l,"factory_id":"1","infos":"depose st geosmes","waste_adr":"Foyer mutualiste de montbard     207 rue charles de     gaulle","name":"Dupond","no_waste":null,"tour_id":"1","begin_hour":"08:00:00","internal_erro    r":null,"fax":"03 80 91 54     60","collector_id":"1","status":"0","img_path":null,"producer_id":"1","adress":"Foyer     mutualiste de montbard 207 rue charles de gaulle","waste_code":"21500","miscellaneous":"Mme     loiseau cadre de sante","downtime":"2","id_erp":"C10018-    1","email":"Dupond.patrick@gmail.com","sequence":"1","siret":"732 829 320 00074"}
03-14 09:17:13.699: I/OnPostExecute -> after setAdapter -> tour_id(1351): id :1
```

EDIT 2: I put Log on each step to show you, that my variable is fill until method **set_tour_id** is called and when I start the new activity, the id is null o_o:

```
03-14 09:41:31.631: I/JARRAY: [{"waste_adr":"Foyer mutualiste de montbard 207 rue charles de gaulle","name":"Dupond","no_waste":null,"tour_id":"1"}]
03-14 09:41:31.631: I/ListCrossingPoint --> set_tour_id(String new_tour_id) -> tour_id:  id :1
03-14 09:41:31.631: I/Asynctask -> OnPostExecute -> after set_tour_id -> tour_id: id :1
03-14 09:42:06.987: I/ListCrossingPoint --> OnClickItemSelected -> tour_id:  id :null
03-14 09:42:06.987: I/ActivityManager(300): START {cmp=com.main/com.infotour.InfoTour (has extras) u=0} from pid 1481
```

Comment: `this.tour_id` i snull

Comment: inside `onPostExecute` you are probably redeclaring `tour_id`

Comment: @SiddharthVyas i know is here , it's my question

Comment: @blackbelt i declared a variable tour_id at the beginning of OnPostExecute, but in the same time, it's in this variable that i save my json_data.getString("tour_id")

Comment: then, as I told, you are redeclaring it, hiding the scope of the member class.

Comment: @laalto i said what is it, it's the variable of my class which contain the method **set_tour_id*

Comment: @blackbelt i declared nowhere else my variable , don't forget that is in OnPostExecute and my variable tour_id that i want to send , is in tha ListCrossingPoint.class which is the class where i called the asynctask

Comment: Let's try again. On the top of onPostExecute you declare `String tour_id`, did I understood correctly?

Comment: @blackbelt yes i declare String tour_id on the top of my OnPostExecute

Comment: then you declare it on top of your class, as class member, `String tour_id`. I am assuming that you have the `AsyncTask` as inner class. did I understood/assuming correctly?

Comment: @blackbelt i declare private String tour_id in the ListCrossingPoint.class , my asynctask is in an other class , that i called like this : AsyncTaskListCrossingPoint asynchroneTaskListingCrossingPoint = new AsyncTaskListCrossingPoint(ListCrossingPoint.this, maListViewPerso, this.driver_id);
   asynchroneTaskListingCrossingPoint.execute();                                       it's not in the same file

Comment: and how do you return this value from the AsyncTask to your class?

Comment: @blackbelt i try to return this value with the method **set_tour_id(tour_id)** which is at the end of the OnPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

`this.lcp` where you set the `tour_id` seems to refer some other object and `tour_id` in your activity is not set. Possibly changing `this.tour_id` to `this.lcp.tour_id` helps. In any case, either

- the `tour_id` has not yet been set (it's an async task after all), or
- the `tour_id` you set is a different `tour_id`.

As you've observed, attempting to log a `null` message causes this NPE. If a `null` message can sometimes legitimately be logged, you can use Hariharan's method to prevent the NPE. Otherwise it's just fixing the symptoms and not the reason.

Comment: the method **set_tour_id** take a param tour_id that i declared in the OnPostExecute , and that i fill with **json_data.getString("tour_id")** which return a value. So in my ListCrossingPoint the private variable should be fill, no ? like a setteur

Comment: i changed directly in the OnPostExecute the line **this.lcp.set_tour_id(tour_id)** by directly **this.lcp.tour_id = tour_id** , but it's the same , Logs say me that when i click on the item , the tour_id is null whereas in the AZsyncTask is = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

From the Logcat

```
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 08:38:00.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

**println needs a message** may be your **tour_id** or **this.tour_id** is null try like below add `""+this.tour_id`

```
Log.i("tour id OnClickItemSelected", ""+this.tour_id);

Log.i("OnPostExecute -> after setAdapter -> tour_id ", ""+tour_id);
```

and

```
Log.i("ListCrossingPoint_tour_id", ""+this.tour_id);
```

then use `tour_id` while initilization only use `this.tour_id`

Comment: i did it, and i have no error now, but i see that my private variable **this.tour_id** which is in my ListCrossingPoint , which is set by the method *set_tour_id** which is in the AsyncTask , is null , whereas the Log which is the asynctask , show me that it's not null

Comment: this only avoids NPE not fix it.

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi Use `tour_id` as Global variable in `ListCrossingPoint` then use it and initilize inside asynctask now you can use it.

Comment: @Hariharan yes i going to try this and i come back

Comment: @Hariharan i don't see how i do, because my method putExtra to send variable in the intent , can't have a variable of type Global and in the asynctask i can't put my String variable tour_id in this global variable, unless I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem. Instead of create ListCrossingPoint object directly in the Asynctask , i create an Asynctask objet in the ListCrossingPoint and get the variable with a getter. I had a probleme i think with object reference.